# Using CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am having troubles understanding CSS transition even when what I think is obvious should work but it doesn't. What I am trying to accomplish is a little complex than this, but this simple example shows how I think I don't understand how CSS transitions work yet.

I want the `flex-direction` property of a container to change from `column` to `row`, but the change shouldn't be instantaneous, but rather slowly so it can be seen. I've implemented the code below, but it still doesn't work even when I think it should.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: teal;
  transition: flex-direction 5s ease;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.container:hover {
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

not everything in animatable. am sure you know that you can not animate display property, same goes for flex-direction, its not animatable.

Answer (score 1):

Flex-direction is not an animatable property in CSS.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

This effect may be done through javascript however.

```
console.clear();

var group = document.querySelector(".group");
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
var total = nodes.length;
var ease  = Power1.easeInOut;
var boxes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    
  var node = nodes[i];
  
  // Initialize transforms on node
  TweenLite.set(node, { x: 0 });
   
  boxes[i] = {
    transform: node._gsTransform,
    x: node.offsetLeft,
    y: node.offsetTop,
    node    
  };
} 

group.addEventListener("mouseenter", layout);
group.addEventListener("mouseleave", layout);

function layout() {

  group.classList.toggle("reorder");  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    
    var box = boxes[i];
        
    var lastX = box.x;
    var lastY = box.y;   
    
    box.x = box.node.offsetLeft;
    box.y = box.node.offsetTop;
    
    // Continue if box hasn't moved
    if (lastX === box.x && lastY === box.y) continue;
    
    // Reversed delta values taking into account current transforms
    var x = box.transform.x + lastX - box.x;
    var y = box.transform.y + lastY - box.y;  
    
    // Tween to 0 to remove the transforms
    TweenLite.fromTo(box.node, 0.5, { x, y }, { x: 0, y: 0, ease });    
  } 
}
```

See: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/eJGrPN

Comment: Thank you for this @Ryan, but I'm afraid I wouldn't want to go into such complexity. I checked out the codepen and its very nice, thanks for such ideas, might need it in the future who knows.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is a nice idea, but transitions does not work with flex direction properties, only properties using quantified values of compatible units can transition between two of those values, like measurements and colors.

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/cfr2bwuz/4/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fiddle example @GloryToPeePo, but then I have a question. Why did the change from `flex-direction: column` to `flex-direction: row` became slow just because we increased or decreased the `width` and `height`?